# In c++, is it safe to use std::numeric_limits<double>::max() as a special "flag"?

Tags: c++, remove-if, numeric-limits, erase-remove-idiom

Given

```
std::vector<double> a;
std::vector<int> ind;
```

where `ind` is <sup>1</sup>sorted in ascending order.

I want to do the equivalent of the following:

```
for (auto it=ind.rbegin();it!=ind.rend();it++) a.erase(a.begin() + *it);
```

I came up with this:

```
for (auto it=ind.begin();it!=ind.end();it++) 
   a[*it] = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
std::erase(std::remove(a.begin(),a.end(),std::numeric_limits<double>::max()),a.end());
```

This is very fast, but it doesn't feel right to use the std::numeric_limits::max() as a flag in this context.

Of course feelings shouldn't play too much into the equation ... clearly comparing the doubles within the std::remove is safe, and the limit will never occur in practice in this vector in a working application, so it should be ok, no?

Any thoughts on this?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>)  Ref [comment by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548637/in-c-is-it-safe-to-use-stdnumeric-limitsdoublemax-as-a-special-flag#comment45410645_28548637). – Alf</sup>

Comment: It's impossible to rule out a vector already containing that value, since you yourself show that it's possible for a vector to contain that value. There's no way to answer this unless you clearly document which assumptions are valid, and which aren't. Another assumption seems to be that the elements of `ind` are in increasing order and without duplicates, but you don't actually say so in your question.

Comment: There are other values you can choose as flags: positive and negative inf, as well as NaN.

Comment: It may be better to use `std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()` or `std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()` instead, if it is known that none of the values in the arrays will be that value.

Comment: Yes, in my case the elements of ind are sorted, hence the reverse iteration alternative/equivalent.

Comment: Good points re infinity or quiet_NaN. They will never appear in the array unless something else is seriously wrong ...

Comment: I wouldn't use NAN since it's hard to test for it - none of the standard algorithms will work with it.

Comment: Can you accidentally get infinity by dividing by zero, or will that cause an exception?

Comment: I think if `double a=1./0;` then `std::isinf(a)` evaluates to true. Not sure about the exception. In my case I could check for infs upfront since they should not occur in my context.

But it seems it might be better to implement my own erase-remove idiom which can use the entries in `ind` rather than the values do identify entries to delete.

Comment: What's wrong with your first snippet?

Comment: Perhaps nothing, but as the first reply points out there is a possibility that  `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()` is already a number in the vector, and hence the operation will fail.

Ideally, I would have wanted to reserve a "special" double which I could have used as a flag, for example by using `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()` as the flag, but then at the same time reducing the max double for everybody else to the second-to-largest possible double value.

Comment: @shabbi: the direct approach in the first snippet is O(a.size()*ind.size()).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at your "baseline" code, that you say you want to do the "equivalent" of:

```
std::vector<double> a;
std::vector<int> ind;

for (auto it = ind.rbegin(); it != ind.rend(); it++)
    a.erase(a.begin() + *it);
```

What we gather from this is that `ind` is a vector of indexes in `a` which should be removed, and that they are sorted ascending.  Those indexes must be removed from `a`.  I assume your goal is to do this efficiently in terms of space and time.

If you think about it in terms of the minimum number of operations required, you have to shift many/most/all of the elements in `a` in order to erase the ones indicated by `ind`.  You don't want to `erase()` several times because this means shifting some elements more than once.  One optimal solution (in the general case, not imposing special requirements on the values in `a`) looks like this:

```
size_t slow = 0; // where we are currently copying "to"
std::vector<int> inditer = ind.begin();
for (size_t fast = 0; fast != a.size(); ++fast) {
    if (inditer != ind.end() && *inditer == fast) {
        // "remove" this element by ignoring it
        ++inditer;
    } else {
        a[slow] = a[fast];
        ++slow;
    }
}
a.resize(slow);
```

Now, you could probably reformulate this using STL algorithms and a custom predicate (functor) which remembers its "current" position in `ind`, but it will not be much less code and it might be harder to understand.

Comment: Thanks a lot - yes, I think that the solution will be to just implement something like this. 

Somewhat surprising though that there's no analog to std::remove for this particular situation. I would guess it's a common case.

Comment: @Jens: I can't recall wanting to do anything like this, but even if it were more directly supported by the STL, there are a couple issues: (1) your `ind` deals in integers rather than iterators, and (2) `ind` must be sorted.  The STL algorithms tend to be more basic/general/widely-applicable.  Think of the STL as a set of examples of what you can do with iterators, rather than a toolbox with fixed contents.